# Insertion Sort on an array of strings in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

If I have an array of strings, such as

```
string[] names = {"John Doe", "Doe John", "Another Name", "Name Another"};
```

How do I sort this array, using insertion sort?

Wikipedia has some examples: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Sorting/Insertion_sort#C.23

```
static void InsertSort(IComparable[] array)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        IComparable value = array[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (array[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))
        {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j--;
        }
        array[j + 1] = value;
    }
}
```

and

```
static void InsertSort<T>(IList<T> list) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        T value = list[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (list[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))
        {
            list[j + 1] = list[j];
            j--;
        }
        list[j + 1] = value;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work on my array of strings, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Would I not run

```
InsertSort(names); // like so?
```

Comment: @Larsenal, no, I'm just using a simple example.

Comment: I bet that you have a typo/bug in your client code around your `InsertSort(names);` call. You might simply be referencing the wrong array when you're checking on the success of your sort method. Please post your client code rather than the InsertSort method which is already well known and tested.

Comment: I'm actually reading strings from a file and I have the array set to [16] but the amount of lines aren't actually 16, so I need to figure out a way to have a variable-sized array.

Comment: If your requirement is for variable-sized array , you can tink of sing List<string> also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] names = { "John Doe", "Doe John", "Another Name", "Name Another" };
        InsertSort(names);
        foreach (var item in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    static void InsertSort(IComparable[] array)
    {
        int i, j;

        for (i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            IComparable value = array[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while ((j >= 0) && (array[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))
            {
                array[j + 1] = array[j];
                j--;
            }
            array[j + 1] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As expected it prints:

```
Another Name
Doe John
John Doe
Name Another
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation:

```
public static void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
{
    T t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

public static void InsertionSort<T>(this T[] a) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    a.InsertionSort(Comparer<T>.Default.Compare);
}

public static void InsertionSort<T>(this T[] a, Comparison<T> c)
{
    int n = a.Length;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        for (int k = i; k > 0 && c(a[k], a[k - 1]) < 0; --k)
            Swap(ref a[k], ref a[k - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do some class to do this:

```
public static class InsertionSort<T> where T : System.IComparable<T>
{
    public static void Sort(ref T[] array)
    {
        T[] tmp = new T[array.Length];
        tmp[0] = array[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int place = FindProperPlace(tmp, array[i]);
            ExpandArray(ref tmp, place);
            tmp[place] = array[i];
        }

        array = tmp;
    }

    private static int FindProperPlace(T[] numbersArray, T number)
    {
        int j;

        for (j = 0; j < numbersArray.Length; j++)
        {
            if (number.CompareTo(numbersArray[j]) < 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return j;
    }

    private static void ExpandArray(ref T[] tmp, int place)
    {
        for (int i = tmp.Length - 1; i > place; i--)
        {
            tmp[i] = tmp[i - 1];
        }
    }
}
```